# Existe alguna forma de hacer esto con random en python?

Tags: python

```
"6d1d2b3e-6a85-4ab9-a268-1eb3dfa1ff3d".randomUUID().toString().replace("-", "").toUpperCase().substring(0, 27)
```

Tengo entendido que debo usar la libreria random y la libreria de replace, pero no entiendo muy bien lo que es toString()  y .toUpperCase().substring(0, 27), gracias de ante mano por leer mi duda (lenguaje kotlin, lo del codigo anterior)

Comment: ```toString()``` transforma las cosas a strings o cadenas de texto, ```toUpperCase()``` sirve para transformar el texto a mayúsculas y ```subString()``` se utiliza para extraer una subida cadena de una cadena, ```subString(inicio,fin)```

Comment: Oh, en ese caso se puede poner en el mismo orden que en python pero con sus respectivas librerias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`toString()` sería `str(variable)`, `toUpperCase()` sería `var.upper()` y  `subString(inicio,fin)` sería `cadena[inicio:fin]`

Comment: Gracias!! Como seria randomUUID? pense que era usando la libreria uuid pero no se si estoy seguro

Comment: No conozco muy bien esa librería en kotlin pero en python lo haces con ```import random``` y la utilizas así ```random.randint(1,100)``` pones los números que quieres y esto te devuelve números enteros